# How to enable "no ping" when using nmap from python

Tags: python, nmap

How to enable the equivalent of -PN (or -P0) command line option for nmap when using the python-nmap?

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
>>> nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
>>> nm.command_line()
'nmap -oX - -p 22-443 -sV 127.0.0.1'
```

The goals is the have -PN (or -P0) in the above... how can I obtain this?

Comment: Please note that `-P0` has not been the preferred name for this option since 2007 (version 4.22SOC8). Please use `-Pn`, as this reduces confusion with `-PO` (IP Protocol host discovery).

Comment: OK, you're right and I've modified the question as such. I'm a legacy user I guess ;-)

Comment: No problem. We don't have any reason to stop supporting `-P0` as an alias, so it's not really critical, but there is nice symmetry between `-Pn`, `-sn`, and `-n` now. (`-PN` is also a deprecated form, and `-sn` used to be `-sP`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly pass the option using `arguments` argument:

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
>>> nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443', arguments='-P0')  # <----
{'nmap': ...}
>>> nm.command_line()
u'nmap -oX - -p 22-443 -P0 127.0.0.1'
```